# Script Fu - Brightness

Tags: gimp, script-fu

I was wondering if anyone knows how to use script-fu in order to have gimp read in an image, modify the brightness/contrast and then save the image.

Thanx

Comment: Googling "script-fu brightness" returns some interesting matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into ImageMagick and it's command-line tools.

Comment: How is the answer, to using script-fu and gimp, imageMagik?!?  And why was it chosen as the correct answer?